# MSYS2 on Win7 prints "Can't find file" after every command?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, msys2

I just installed **MSYS2** on my Windows 7 VM and the only stuff I've really done so far was that I modified my ~/.bashrc file by adding a few lines.

The only stuff I added to the file was a few alias cmds, an export cmd, and I modified the PS1 variable. See below:

```
alias ll='ls -l'
alias la='ls -A'
alias cls='clear'
export PATH="$PATH:/home/Matt/bin"
PS1=$(print '\033]0;${PWD}\n\033[32m${USER}@${HOSTNAME}:\033[33m${PWD/${HOME}/\~}>\033[0m ')
```

Other then that stuff above, that's all I've really done. So after making the changes to **~/.bashrc** I exited from MSYS2's command prompt and then restarted MSYS2 to make the .bashrc changes go into effect. *I know I could have just re-sourced the file but I just quickly exited and restarted instead...*

Then, after I restarted MSYS2 this printed as the first line in the terminal --> ***"Can't find file"*** and then after everytime I hit enter at the cmd prompt it prints "Can't find file" just before the next prompt prints to the screen, like below:

```
Terminal shows this when I start-up MSYS2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Can't find file
Matt@My-Win7VM:~> ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 My-Win7VM+Matt My-Win7VM+None 0 Jun  3 12:01 bin
Can't find file
Matt@My-Win7VM:~>
Can't find file
Matt@My-Win7VM:~>
Can't find file
Matt@My-Win7VM:~>
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any ideas what file it could be talking about that it can't seem to find..?
Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance,
Matt

Comment: Ok I think I found the problem. I ran the **env** command, and the **PS1** environment variable was showing `PS1=Can't find file \033]0;${PWD}\n\033[1;31m${USER}@${HOSTNAME}:\033[1;34m${PWD/${HOME}/\~}>\033[0m`. So I switched the PS1 export line in my .bashrc file to just a double quoted variable assignment, instead of including the print command. Because it looks like the 'print' command is trying to be run from _"/c/Windows/system32/print"_ and that print cmd is expecting a filename, not a string. So switching it to just an assignment statment fixed the error...

Answer (score 2):

Ok I think I found the problem.

I ran the **env** command, and the **PS1** environment variable was showing this

```
PS1=Can't find file \033]0;${PWD}\n\033[1;31m${USER}@${HOSTNAME}:\033[1;34m${PWD/${HOME}/\~}>\033[0m
```

So I removed the `export PS1=${print ...}` line from my `~/.bashrc` file to just a double quoted variable assignment, instead of using the `print` command.

Because it looks like the `print` command is trying to be run from *"/c/Windows/system32/print"* and if you pass it a string you can see the error that was showing:

```
$ which print
/c/Windows/system32/print

$ print "Hello World"
Can't find file Hello World
```

So as you can see, that print command is expecting a filename, and not a string. So switching it to just an assignment statement like below, fixed the error:

```
export PS1="\033[1;31m${USER}@${HOSTNAME}:\033[1;34m${PWD/${HOME}/\~}>\033[0m "
```

Now everything seems ok.

**EDIT:**
Ran into new problem where the directory in the prompt wasn't changing when I switched dirs... Found out I was using the wrong method. So I found the PS1 switches and now it's all better this time:

```
PS1="\033[1;31m\u@\h:\033[0m\033[1;34m\w>\033[0m "
```

-Matt

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've copied your `$PS1` from `/etc/profile`

Try the `$PS1` variable from `/etc/bash.bashrc` instead:

```
# Set a default prompt of: user@host, MSYSTEM variable, and current_directory
PS1='\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[35m\]$MSYSTEM\[\e[0m\] \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n\$ '
```